# JComboBox action won't perform

Tags: java, eclipse, actionlistener, jcombobox

Let say the user chose petrol stations. The frame will change and the user will be able to choose a location and the list of petrol stations in that location will appear below the combobox.

So I've tried adding another action listener inside the if statement, using another if else and I also tried switch statements but both won't show the output. So how do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

**This is the shortened version of my code before adding the 2nd action listener**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Testing5 {
private JFrame frame1, frame2;
private ActionListener action, action2;
private JButton PetrolStations, back, Foods;
private JComboBox locationChooser;
final static String[] location = {"Petaling Jaya", "Port Klang", "Kuala Lumpur"};

public void  HELPMEGUI() {

    frame1 = new JFrame("Frame 1");
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      

    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2));

    PetrolStations = new JButton ("PetrolStations");
    Foods = new JButton ("Foods");      
    back = new JButton ("Back");

    locationChooser = new JComboBox(location);

    action = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();          

            if (button == PetrolStations) {
                frame2 = new JFrame("FRAME 2");
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
                frame2.add(locationChooser, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame2.add(back, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                frame2.setSize(300, 300);
                frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame1.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if (button == Foods) {
                frame2 = new JFrame("FRAME 2");
                frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
                frame2.add(locationChooser, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame2.add(back, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                frame2.setSize(300, 300);
                frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame1.setVisible(false);

            }

            else if (button == back ) {
                frame1.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setVisible(false);
                frame2.dispose();
            }
        }
    }; 

    PetrolStations.addActionListener(action);
    Foods.addActionListener(action);
    back.addActionListener(action);
    locationChooser.addActionListener(action2);

    contentPanel.add(PetrolStations);
    contentPanel.add(Foods);

    frame1.getContentPane().add(contentPanel);
    frame1.setSize(640, 400);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}

public static void main(String...args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new Testing5().HELPMEGUI();
        }
    });
}

}
```

**EDIT:**

**This is what I tried to do**

```
 action2 = new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JComboBox locationSelected = (JComboBox) e.getSource();

                        if (locationSelected == Kuala Lumpur ) {
                            System.out.println("Address 1");
                        }
                    }
                };
```

**2nd try**

```
   action2 = new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     int temp;

                     if(e.getSource() == locationChooser) {
                         temp = locationChooser.getSelectedIndex();

                         switch (temp) {
                         case 0: System.out.println("Address 1"); break;
                         case 1: System.out.println("Address 2"); break;
                         }
                     }
                    }
                    };}
```

Comment: `action2` is never initialised (it's `null`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer This is the code before I added the new action

Comment: Well, that was unhelp

Comment: When do you create an instance of `action2`? Don't make edits as continuations to the question, go back, make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which clearly demonstrates your problem - leave out the guess work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the context of your action listener definition, so I think you might have it in the wrong place.  Here's how I did it, and it seems to work:

```
    PetrolStations.addActionListener(action);
    Foods.addActionListener(action);
    back.addActionListener(action);
    action2 = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int temp;

            if (e.getSource() == locationChooser) {
                temp = locationChooser.getSelectedIndex();

                switch (temp) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println("Address 1");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Address 2");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    locationChooser.addActionListener(action2);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't state this on the question, I will edit. But this code is the code before I add the 2nd action listener inside the 1st action listener

Comment: Show me that 2nd action listener and I'll see if I have a better answer for you...

Comment: I've added two set of codes which I have tried